# Control spacing in awk output

Tags: bash, sed, awk, grep, gnuplot

I have two text files. hash_only.txt and final_output.txt
hash_only.txt looks like below.

```
193548
401125
401275
```

final_output.txt looks like below.

```
193548      1199687744  5698758206701808640
193548      1216464960  5698758206761818112
193548      1216464960  5698758206778417152
193548      4236691520  5698758206778945280
401125      2138607488  5698762375908890880
401125       863932288  5698762375909423360
401125      3884158848  5698762375910044160
401125      2609483648  5698762375911032320
```

I have written a script as shown below.

```
awk '
FNR==NR {
    hash[$1]
    next
}
$1 in hash {
    print $2,'\t',$3 >> "ecast_print_"$1;
}' hash_only.txt final_output.txt
```

For all the values in hash_only.txt such as 193548,401125 etc I want to extract column 2,3 from the file 'final_output.txt' where column 1 matches 193548,401125 etc and output 
column 2,3 to print_193548, print_401125 etc.
This produces the output as shown below.

```
1133254688 5698771509078629376
1150031904 5698771509371165696
1150031904 5698771510035551232
4170258464 5698771510036082688
2895583264 5698771510036715520
1620908064 5698771510037202176
346232864 5698771510037665280
3366459424 5698771510038193664
2091784224 5698771510332259072
817109024 5698771510332816128
3837335584 5698771510333344512
2562660384 5698771510339882240
```

As you can see above the output is misaligned where the length of the first field is less than normal.I want the second line to start at the exact location.I need this so as to give it as an input to gnuplot.Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's|.*|/^& /{s/.\\{12\\}//;w ecast_print_&\n}|' hash_only.txt |
sed -nf - final_output.txt
```

Explanation:

Creates a sed script from the `hash_only.txt` file that writes out matching lines to a filename `ecast_print_` with the key appended. The first 12 characters are deleted from the input file supplied to the sed script.

Answer (score 2):

You might look into using [`printf`](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Printf-Examples.html) to get fields to have a consistent width.

Also, gnuplot does not mind if fields are not perfectly aligned in the file, if that is what you are going for.  All that is necessary is that fields be separated by whitespace.